# C++. Предварительное объявление членов классов за их пределами

Tags: c++, классы, объявление

У меня сложилась такая ситуация, что есть два класса, каждый из которых нуждается в конструкторе другого. Для этого нужно, чтобы они видели не только объявления (прототипы), но и определения друг друга одновременно, что невозможно. Значит, каждый класс должен видеть сверху по крайней мере прототип конструктора другого.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

class Euros;
Euros::Euros(double euros = 0);

class Dollars
{
    private:
        double m_dollars;

    public:
        Dollars(double dollars = 0) : m_dollars(dollars)
        {
        }

        operator double() const { return m_dollars; }
        operator Euros() const { return Euros(m_dollars * 0.89); }

        double getDollars() const { return m_dollars; }
        void setDollars(double dollars) { m_dollars = dollars; }
};

class Euros
{
    private:
        double m_euros;
    public:
        Euros(double euros) : m_euros(euros)
        {
        }

        operator double() const { return m_euros; }
        operator Dollars() const { return Dollars(m_euros * 1.12); }

        double getEuros() const { return m_euros; }
        void setEuros(double euros) { m_euros = euros; }
};
```

Здесь для каждого класса перегружается операция преобразования типов друг в друга, для чего требуется возвращать вновь созданный с помощью конструктора экземпляр противоположного класса. С классом Euros всё нормально, т.к. он видит полное определение класса Dollars, а значит видит и конструктор. С классом Dollars всё наоборот: он вообще не видит Euros. В 3 строке я объявил прототип Euros, но этого недостаточно, т.к. для создания объекта нужен ещё и конструктор.

Я знаю, что методы класса достаточно только объявить внутри него, а определение может быть уже после за его пределами. Но я не знаю, можно ли сделать наоборот: определить внутри класса, а объявить перед ним. В 4 строке я попытался это сделать, но получил ошибку "invalid use of incomlete type 'class Euros'". Естественно, были и другие ошибки, вытекающие из этой, но данная ошибка источник всех проблем.

Попытки гуглить привели к осознанию того, что я не способен сформулировать вопрос на языке, понятном для поисковика. Как можно решить этот замкнутый круг?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простое вынесите реализации "перекрёстных" методов (одного из них) наружу из определения класса и поместите ниже - после определения второго класса

```
class Euros;

class Dollars
{
  ...
  operator Euros() const;
  ...
};

class Euros
{
  ...
  operator Dollars() const { return Dollars(m_euros * 1.12); }
  ...
};

inline Dollars::operator Euros() const
{
  return Euros(m_dollars * 0.89);
}
```

Вы и сами написали об этом в вопросе: "Я знаю, что методы класса достаточно только объявить внутри него, а определение может быть уже после за его пределами." Только применять это знание вам надо было обычным способом к вашим операторам преобразования, а не каким-то "вывернутым" образом к конструкторам.